# Recommended ASP.NET combobox control

Tags: asp.net, combobox

Currently we have a makeshift combobox which is comprised of a textbox, an arrow image, and a list - obviously not the best method.

Are there any recommended ASP.NET comboboxes other than the one contained within the AJAX control toolkit?  I would prefer a *free* one if possible.

A combobox is a dropdown that also allows manual editing of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used the one [from Obout](http://www.obout.com/combobox/) in the past and now the one in the [DevExpress package](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/ASPxComboBox/LargeDataSource.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should check [telerik.](http://www.telerik.com/) lots of useful controls.